# How to take date as input from user?

Tags: python, datetime, input

I just want to write a script for taking the date
as input from user, if user don't enter date then program should take system's date.
I tried the following code. How can I do this by using any if-else condition or any functions in Python.

```
date_entry = input('Enter a date in YYYY-MM-DD format:')

year, month, day = map(int, date_entry.split('-'))

date1 = datetime.date(year, month, day)
```

How can I write this script for above problem?

Comment: date_entry = input('Enter a date in YYYY-MM-DD format:')
    if date_entry:
        year, month, day = map(int, date_entry.split('-'))
    else:
        # Here you take current date from datetime
    date1 = datetime.date(year, month, day)

Answer (score 0):

It's best to use exception handling for this matter.

Use `try` and `except` to handle any exceptions thrown by `datetime`  module whenever any input given is not according to the format wanted.

```
try:
    date_entry = input('Enter a date in YYYY-MM-DD format:')

    year, month, day = map(int, date_entry.split('-'))

    date1 = datetime.date(year, month, day)

except ValueError:

    date1=datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```